Easy-RSA creating Req file?
I'm using Easy-RSA to build a SSL Certificate, although I know it's backbone is OpenSSL. I do not know how to do it directly in OpenSSL, knowing that is a separate topic. I would appreciate the insight on how to do this.
The issue which I'm facing is, on this page; https://easy-rsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuring-easy-rsa under Import Requests to the CA this being after have created the CA.crt file. What is the requested req file which this command is asking for. After running the command to create the CA file that has created a req directory but it is empty. Followed by asking for the name of the request. From what I understand based on what the req file is, the name of the request file is whatever name I choose based on this req file.

Certificate request files are generated by the CA's clients and are pretty much an "unsigned certificate" that the client is asking you to sign. They contain the client's public key which will go into the final certificate, plus the desired certificate subject (which the CA will happily ignore).
Therefore, as a CA, you'd normally receive CSR files from users or admins who need a certificate.
Easy-RSA can generate a request; as far as I can see, the "name" is just the output file name, as the "requested" certificate subject is specified later.
easy-rsa gen-req foobar

One popular way to create a certificate request is openssl req -new (you might have seen it used to create a self-signed certificate with the -x509 option, but if you run it without that option, it'll output a request instead). It can be used either with a previously generated keypair or generate one itself.
openssl req -new -subj "/O=Widgets Inc/CN=mail.example.com" -out widgets.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout widgets.key

